# Select 1 row each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to select one row per day table idea below:

```
ID|PageID|DateTime  |Value|SiteID
1 |  1   |2021/03/06| 2001| 1
1 |  1   |2021/03/06| 2002| 1
1 |  2   |2021/03/06| 2003| 1
1 |  3   |2021/03/06| 2004| 1
1 |  4   |2021/03/06| 2004| 1
1 |  1   |2021/03/07| 2004| 1
1 |  2   |2021/03/07| 2005| 1
1 |  3   |2021/03/07| 2006| 1
```

So the site has multiple links with seperate links but PageID is a bit redundant here I'm trying to group by SiteID and retreive one row for each day grouped by SiteID
The value doesn't specifically matter as long as its once a day.

Attempt:

```
SELECT [DateTime], [Followers], [SiteID]
FROM test
WHERE datetime IN (
    SELECT MAX(datetime)
    FROM test Where SiteID = 1
    GROUP BY datetime
);
```

Comment: Please show us you attempt

Comment: SELECT
  [DateTime]
      ,[Followers]
      ,[SiteID] 
FROM test
WHERE datetime IN (
  SELECT MAX(datetime) 
  FROM test
  Where SiteID = 1
  GROUP BY datetime
 );

Answer (score 1):

until you provide desired output , here is one way :

```
select *
from (select * , row_number() over (partition by SiteId,Date) rn from table) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  But if the value is a `datetime`, you need to extract the date:

```
select *
from (select t.* ,
             row_number() over (partition by SiteId, convert(date, datetime) order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If performance is an issue, then a correlated subquery might have better performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datetime = (select min(t2.datetime)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.siteId = t.siteId and
                          t2.date >= convert(date, t.date) and
                          t2.date < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, t2.date))
                   );
```

Note:  This assumes that `datetime` is unique.  You can use any column for the comparison that is unique.

Comment: performance wise, do you think CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1) method would be better than windowing function? I've had a similar situation recently and the difference was quite large, but might have been situation specific.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . For one table `CROSS APPLY` wouldn't make a difference in this case.  However, a correlated subquery might be faster.  `APPLY` would replace a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by Row_Number() Over(Partition By SiteId,convert(date, datetime) Order by (select null))
```